# Find and replace quotation marks in a text file

Tags: vba, file, ms-access, replace, double-quotes

I have an Access database that pulls information from different sources and populates a .TXT file that is then imported into another application.

My issue is that my .TXT file has quotation marks in, and I need to just find all of these and replace them with nothing using VBA.

I have the following code to open the file and do a find and replace.

```
Dim objFSO
Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2
Dim objTS 'define a TextStream object
Dim strContents As String
Dim fileSpec As String

fileSpec = Forms![frm_MAIN_MENU]![txt_MAIN_ORDER_LOCATION].Value

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objTS = objFSO.OpenTextFile(fileSpec, ForReading)
strContents = objTS.ReadAll
strContents = Replace(strContents, "", "")
objTS.Close

Set objTS = objFSO.OpenTextFile(fileSpec, ForWriting)
objTS.Write strContents
objTS.Close
    End Sub
```

However, the quotation marks within the quotation marks is giving me a headache.

Comment: How is it populating that file that it has inverted commas (assuming you mean a single quote here?). If they are present in the data you are collecting then stripping them out inside of access would be easiest. If they are an artifact of the mechanism you are using to write out the TXT, then perhaps that is a feature you can turn off?

Comment: Sorry, my question was vague. I adjusted accordingly

Comment: What is the inverted comma character you are seeing. Is it `'` or `"` or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try replacing

```
strContents = Replace(strContents, "", "")
```

with

```
strContents = Replace(strContents, """", "")
```

Comment: Awesome, that seems to have done the trick! Thank you very much